# SSH can't connect today - yesterday was fine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, directadmin

Just created instance on compute for CentOS 6. Installed Directadmin control panel (directadmin.com) and could ssh to my external IP yesterday 104.155.217.95 on port 22 using my putty private keys.

Today I can't connect to it (didn't change anything) but DirectAdmin is working fine and I can login to it http://104.155.217.95:2222

:(

Answer (score 0):

Might be SSH services is down on your server OR port 22 is blocked, Please check this and if port 22 is open then try to add new SSH key with the following link

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys

Comment: How do I check because I can't ssh to it now.

Comment: How do I check because I can't ssh to it now.